# Как вывести блок, если выбран конкретный элемент выпадающего списка?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы, зависимый блок выводился только если в выпадающем списке выбран город Челябинск, иначе блок должен быть скрыт. 
Я предполагал что в коде у выбранного элемента что то будет отличаться и к этому прицепиться, атрибут может быть или еще что, но как посмотрел, они абсолютно одинаковы.

```css
.dependent {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #8F8F8F;
    margin: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<select id="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid" class="form-select">
  <option value="All">Элементы списка</option>
  <option value="708">Златоуст</option>
  <option value="710">Челябинск</option>
</select>


<div class="dependent">Я зависимый блок</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так, с использованием  jquery

```js
var $dependerItem = $('.dependent');
$('#edit-field-sity-tid').change(function() {
  var curentSelectedVal = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  if (curentSelectedVal == 710) {
    $dependerItem.removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $dependerItem.addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.dependent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #8F8F8F;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid" class="form-select">
  <option value="All">Элементы списка</option>
  <option value="708">Златоуст</option>
  <option value="710">Челябинск</option>
</select>

<div class="dependent hide">Я зависимый блок</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

При необходимости множественного показа разных блоков при выборе разных `option`:

```js
document.getElementById('edit-field-sity-tid').onchange = function() {
  var chelyabinksCity = document.querySelector('.dependent');
  switch (this.value) {
    case 'all':
      chelyabinksCity.style.display = 'none';
      break;
    case '708':
      chelyabinksCity.style.display = 'none';
      break;
    case '710':
      chelyabinksCity.style.display = 'block';
      break;
  };
};
```

```css
.dependent {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background: #8F8F8F;
    margin: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<select id="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid" class="form-select">
  <option value="All">Элементы списка</option>
  <option value="708">Златоуст</option>
  <option value="710">Челябинск</option>
</select>

<div class="dependent">Я зависимый блок</div>
```

При необходимости проверки только одного `option` рациональнее проверять вот так:

```js
document.getElementById('edit-field-sity-tid').onchange = function() {
  var chelyabinksCity = document.querySelector('.dependent');
  chelyabinksCity.style.display = ((this.value) == 710 ? 'block' : 'none');
};
```

```css
.dependent {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background: #8F8F8F;
    margin: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<select id="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid" class="form-select">
  <option value="All">Элементы списка</option>
  <option value="708">Златоуст</option>
  <option value="710">Челябинск</option>
</select>

<div class="dependent">Я зависимый блок</div>
```

Comment: проверку на if (){} написать?? ведь в списке элементов может быть около 1000 и больше, а блок должен показываться только у одного, не рационально писать case каждый раз.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов добавил в ответ вариант для одиночной проверки